# Gradle: Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Since today, and I didn't change anything in my Gradle files, there is an error during the building:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.+.
```

For information in my Gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        jcenter()

        maven { url = "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }

        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

        maven { url "https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/cometchat/cometchat-pro-android/maven/" }

        flatDir {
            dirs 'src/main/libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [gradle status](https://status.gradle.com/), jcenter has some issues still.